# Private Browsing Specification

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, safari

I recently ran into a problem with a web application while **private browsing** was enabled so I was wondering if there is a specification about the different private browsing implementations in Firefox, Chrome and Safari? E.g. what exactly is disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For..

- Firefox: [What does Private Browsing not save?](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/private-browsing-browse-web-without-saving-info#w_what-does-private-browsing-not-save)
- Chrome: [Incognito mode (browse in private)](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95464?hl=en)
- Safari: [Safari 5.1 (OS X Lion): Browse privately](http://support.apple.com/kb/ph5000)

That's about as much info is available on the Private Browsing for these browsers. Firefox seems to be the most comprehensive, in listing what Private Browsing does not save. The other two - Chrome and Safari -- are fairly vague, understandably so, since these 2 are not open source.